# How can i generate joint probabilities matrix with R?

Tags: r, function, binary, probability

I am trying to generate a matrix of joint probabilities. It's a symmetric matrix. The main diagonal elements are interpreted as probabilities 
p
(
A
i
)
 that a binary variable 
A
i
 equals 1. The off-diagonal elements  are the probabilities 
p
(
A
i
A
j
)
 that both 
A
i
 and 
A
j
 are 1. This matrix should respond to the following conditions :

0
≤
p
A
i
≤
1

max
(
0
,
p
A
i
+
p
A
j
−
1
)
≤
p
A
i
A
j
≤
min
(
p
A
i
,
p
A
j
)
,
i
≠
j

p
A
i
+
p
A
j
+
p
A
k
−
p
A
i
A
j
−
p
A
i
A
k
−
p
A
j
A
k
≤
1
,
i
≠
j
,
i
≠
k
,
j
≠
k

These conditions are checked with check.commonprob.

I built a function to generate this matrix respecting these conditions:

```
# First I need another function to make the matrix symmetric 

   makeSymm <- function(m) {
  m[upper.tri(m)] <- t(m)[upper.tri(m)]
  return(m) }

  b=matrix(0,10,10)

#The functionthat generates joint probabilities

  joint=function(b,x,y,u,z,k,m){
  repeat{
  diag(b)=runif(k, min=x, max=y)
  b[lower.tri(b,diag=FALSE)]<-runif(m,min=u, max=z)
  b<-makeSymm(b)
  check.commonprob(b)->c
  if(c==TRUE)
  break}
  return(b)}
```

Since b is 10*10 matrix => there is 10 diagonal elements and 45 elements in the lower triangular matrix. I got this result:

```
b=joint(b,0.4,0.6,0.2,0.4,10,45)

> b
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
 [1,] 0.4479626 0.2128775 0.3103472 0.2342798 0.2719423 0.3114339 0.3978305
 [2,] 0.2128775 0.4413829 0.2603543 0.2935595 0.2556380 0.2486850 0.2694443
 [3,] 0.3103472 0.2603543 0.5170409 0.3003153 0.2651415 0.3410199 0.2321201
 [4,] 0.2342798 0.2935595 0.3003153 0.5930984 0.2719581 0.3982266 0.3157343
 [5,] 0.2719423 0.2556380 0.2651415 0.2719581 0.4031691 0.2157856 0.3016181
 [6,] 0.3114339 0.2486850 0.3410199 0.3982266 0.2157856 0.4042654 0.2595399
 [7,] 0.3978305 0.2694443 0.2321201 0.3157343 0.3016181 0.2595399 0.5195244
 [8,] 0.3154185 0.3174374 0.2920965 0.3259053 0.2847335 0.3560568 0.2070868
 [9,] 0.2892746 0.2510410 0.3232922 0.2970148 0.3070217 0.3445408 0.3180946
[10,] 0.2948818 0.2264481 0.3210267 0.2866854 0.3783635 0.3427585 0.2306935
           [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
 [1,] 0.3154185 0.2892746 0.2948818
 [2,] 0.3174374 0.2510410 0.2264481
 [3,] 0.2920965 0.3232922 0.3210267
 [4,] 0.3259053 0.2970148 0.2866854
 [5,] 0.2847335 0.3070217 0.3783635
 [6,] 0.3560568 0.3445408 0.3427585
 [7,] 0.2070868 0.3180946 0.2306935
 [8,] 0.5958957 0.2710500 0.2318991
 [9,] 0.2710500 0.5003779 0.2512744
[10,] 0.2318991 0.2512744 0.5004233
```

Up to now , everything seems good, but the problem is that when I wanted to generate a 100*100 matrix, I noticed that beyond a dimension of 20*20 the running time becomes so long (hours) and I can't get a result at the end because i have to stop it. 
Do you have any suggestions to improve this function so I can try it on 100*100 matrix ? Also can I stipulate the mean and the standard deviation of the joint probabilities matrix in advance? Thanks !

Comment: Since your `m` is a simple function of your `k` (`m == k*(k-1)/2`, it seems both pointless and potentially misleading to include it as a parameter. Are you sure that all other choices of the parameters (assuming that `0 <= x < y <= 1` and `0 <= u < z <= 1`) are actually possible? In any event, are you just trying to generate examples of such matrices, or are you trying to pick one from the set of all such matrices with uniform probability? The former might be relatively easy, the latter requires either deep theoretical understanding or your current hit and miss approach.

Comment: I am just trying to generate a matrix 100*100 of joint probabilities, not necessarily with uniform probability but since I am new to R this is the only thing I could think about. For the x, y,u,z I tried so many combinations, some of them worked for the 10*10 matrix. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Regarding your latest, migrated, question, it would be nice if you would come over to [stats.SE], link an account, & address comments, upvote, accept, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply trying to generate examples of such matrices and don't have any other constraints, you can do so by generating observations from a population that would be implicitly described by such a matrix and then tabulate the observed probabilities. You can start by writing a function which does the tabulation:

```
p.matrix <- function(A){
  n <- nrow(A)
  k <- ncol(A)
  outer(1:n,1:n,Vectorize(function(i,j) sum(A[i,]*A[j,])))/k
}
```

The above function can take *any* binary matrix and turn it into a matrix of probabilities that will statisfy `check.commonprob`. To get a matrix of a given size you can do something like:

```
prob.matrix <- function(n,p = 0.5){
  k <- max(1000,10*n^2)
  pop <- replicate(k,ifelse(runif(n) < p,1,0))
  p.matrix(pop)
}
```

For example:

```
> M <- prob.matrix(4,c(0.1,0.9,0.3,0.4))
> M
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] 0.098 0.090 0.019 0.042
[2,] 0.090 0.903 0.278 0.366
[3,] 0.019 0.278 0.306 0.121
[4,] 0.042 0.366 0.121 0.410
> bindata::check.commonprob(M)
[1] TRUE
```

For `n = 100` this takes about 30 seconds on my machine.

In this function the resulting variables are basically uncorrelated. To get correlated variables, replace the simple `ifelse()` call by a custom function which e.g. doesn't allow for runs of 3 or more consecutive 1's. If you want finer control on the correlations, you would need to first be clear on just what you would want them to be.

Comment: Thank you. I would also like to enforce the mean of the matrix and its standard deviation in advance. Is it possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by the mean and standard deviation of a matrix? If a random variable is binary then its standard deviation is a function of the mean, so there is only 1 choice. The means would be the diagonal of the matrix. If you don't care about what the off-diagonal elements are, you can stipulate the diagonal elements.

Comment: I mean can i fix the mean of the joint probabilities ( the off diagonal elements ) and their standard deviation . How does the deviation is a function of the mean ? Thank you

Comment: Why if a random variable is binary then its standard deviation is a function of the mean and there is only 1 choice. Actually, based on the standard deviation formula , we can have more than one value for the standard deviation for the same mean. Can you please explain your comment further. I would be so grateful!

Comment: @BS.Mira A binary random variable is [Benoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution). Such random variables have a single parameter, `p`, which is the probability of taking on the value 1. The mean of such a variable *is* `p` and the standard deviation is `sqrt(p*(1-p))`. For example, if the mean is 0.7 then the standard deviation will be `sqrt(0.7*0.3) = sqrt(0.21) = 0.458`. Once `p` is fixed there is no choice in the matter. On the other hand, binary variables which are jointly distributed don't have their correlations determined by their means.

Comment: thank you! but i am talking about the mean and standard deviation of the joint probabilities (the off diagonal terms).

Comment: Can i have the diagonal elements with different probabilities ?

Comment: @BS.Mira I tweaked the definition of `prob.matrix` so that it can take either a single number or a vector of target probabilities for the diagonal. Since the matrix is constructed by a simulation, you don't get the exact values on the diagonal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question: Since i have to genrate a 100*100 matrix I used uniform distribution to generate the diagonal elements e.g M=prob.matrix(80,runif(80,0.4,0.9)) and it has always worked (check.commonprob is always TRUE) but when I tried to generate the diagonal elements with Normal distribution e.g M=prob.matrix(80,rnorm(80,mean=0.5,sd=0.4)), it doesn't work. Any explanations?

Comment: @BS.Mira Probabilities can't be negative. When you generate 80 values which follow that normal distribution you can expect around 8 or 9 to be negative (`pnorm(0,0.5,0.4)` is approximately `0.11` , so about 11% of your observations will be negative -- and another 11% or so will exceed 1, which also makes no sense as a probability).

Comment: @BS.Mira If you want a flexible hyperdistribution on those diagonal probabilities, consider using a [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). But, make sure that you have a principled reason to regard those probabilities as being random, otherwise you risk generating meaningless results.

Comment: Okey thanks! and is there a way too generate such a matrix with of a specific distribution. For example if i want to generate a matrix of joint probabilities such that its distribution is gamma or weidbull ?